# Custom AdapterView with complex positioning of children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I am trying to implement a custom `AdapterView` that draws it's child in own way following [Making your own 3D list](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/&ei=loYrUdTfAa-ziQfM6oGgBg&usg=AFQjCNHaNxzEuTB9d7tyzQQHdpFbiMOCxA&sig2=9-2-KfwYYTJoabj52skmmQ&bvm=bv.42768644,d.aGc). What i am trying to do is draw the children in sort of a surface where they are positioned irregularly and are of irregular sizes. The children are selectable and the `AdapterView` otherwise Functions like a `ListView`. The reason i am using a `AdapterView` is because i want to populate it with a adapter which gets it's data from database. **How do i draw the children in it's position and implement scrolling and selection?**
P.S. The Height of the "Surface" is Fixed and width is set to `match_parent`